# Weaving JSR 349 annotation using AspectJ ITD

Tags: hibernate, aspectj

I have an AspectJ ITD like this. The @NotNull annotation is from the JSR 349 hibernate validator.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclareAnnotation;
@Aspect
  public class InterType {

  @DeclareAnnotation("com.package..*")
  @NotNull Object property;

  @DeclareAnnotation("public * com.package.*(..)")
  @NotNull void setProperty() {}

}
```

My Maven AspectJ plugin is weaving other aspects at compile-time. But the ITD is not weaved.

```
 [INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.7:compile (default) @ HRG ---
 [INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
 [WARNING] Found @DeclareAnnotation while current release does not support   it (se
 e 'com.package.InterType')
    C:\Users\476458\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.4.RELEASE\Logger\src\main\ja
 va\com\hrg\logger\aspect\InterType.java:9
 public class InterType {
         ^^^^^^^^
```

I know that I can add annotations using AspectJ's ITD mechanism. But there seems to be something different with these annotations. What am I missing ?

So I am weaving a compiled annotation and my source code. Is there a different AspectJ configuration required for this ?

Should it be a dependency like this ?

```
            <weaveDependencies>
                <weaveDependency>
                   <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                   <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
                </weaveDependency>
                <weaveDependency>
                   <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
                   <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
                </weaveDependency>
                <weaveDependency>
                   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                   <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
                </weaveDependency>
                <weaveDependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                </weaveDependency>
            </weaveDependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't your pom/versions - `@DeclareAnnotation` has no backing implementation in the AspectJ weaver. It was added as a possible way to do `declare @method`, `declare @field`, `declare @type` and `declare @constructor` in a pure java syntax but it was never finished. Until the weaver supports it you will always get that message indicating.

Comment: I see 2 options. 1. Use aj syntax along with @AspectJ which I use for logging already. 2. Use Spring AOP to add JSR 349 annotations using proxying. I am adding 349 annotations to JAXB generated code. You replied in aspect users list also.

Comment: I am able to do this with code style aspects. But @DeclareAnnotation should be 'deprecated'. It caused a problem because I thought the entire approach fails(adding 349 annotations to JAXB generated code).